# Showing the integral $=0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let
$$I= \int_0^1\mkern-9mu\int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dg(x) \,dg(y)$$
where $f(x,y)= 1$ if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$, otherwise it is $0$ and $g$ is a monotone function.

The integration is w.r.t. Riemann-Stieltjes sense. How can we show that $I=0$?

My try:

Since the integration is over a set of measure zero. The integral should be zero. However, I am not being able to write the proof precisely since here the integration is w.r.t Riemann- Stieltjes sense.
Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have the answer with the correct explanation.  If you prefer, you can break the integral into separate regions, one thin diagonal region containing the line $y=x$.

Comment: Yes...I understand..but still I have confusion. It would be good if you can help.